# Error observing changes to NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I am attempting to save a value to the `NSUserDefaults`. Below is my code.

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setValue:theUrl forKey:PREFS_FEED_URL];
```

The error I'm receiving is `message sent to deallocated instance 0x9495b00`.

This is running on the simulator. I've verified that the prefs variable is not `nil`.

Edit: Complete method below:

```
- (void) exeSave {
    NSString *theUrl = [util isEmptyStr:rssFeedUrl.text] ? nil : [util trimString:rssFeedUrl.text];
    if (!theUrl) {
        [util showToast:@"The URL entered was empty" duration:1];
        return;
    }

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:theUrl];
    if (!url) {
        [util showToast:@"The URL entered was invalid" duration:1];
        return;
    }
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setObject:theUrl forKey:PREFS_FEED_URL];
    [prefs synchronize];
}
```

Edit 2:
I just realized that the error message is referring to a previous `ViewController` - my `RssViewController`. The method above is in my `EditSettingsViewController`. I don't know enough about Objective C to figure out why or how that would occur.

Edit 3:
Upon further inspection, the error goes away when I remove the code that observes changes to `NSUserDefaults`.

The following code is in my `RssViewController`

In the `viewDidLoad` method, I have the following:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"feed_url" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

I remove the observer in the `dealloc` method:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    self.navigationController.sideMenu.menuStateEventBlock = nil;
}
```

I overrode the following method.

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqual:PREFS_FEED_URL]) {
        NSLog(@"user prefs: url changed");
        [self refresh];
    }
}
```

The debugger never reaches the `observeValueForKeyPath` method.

Comment: I think you want `setObject:` instead of `setValue:`. Also, are you using `ARC`?

Comment: Just tried that and received the same failure message. 

Edit: I removed the app from the simulator and relaunched it - same problem.

Comment: If you use `[prefs setObject:theUrl forKey:PREFS_FEED_URL];` it should work. Are you sure that's where it's breaking?

Comment: @msgambel - Yes, using ARC.

Comment: @daltonclaybrook - I've got it in debug and that's the line just before the app bombs.

Comment: @acedanger What does your code for theUrl look like

Comment: @user125697 added edit with the full method

Comment: Looks like you want `[prefs setObject:url forKey:PREFS_FEED_URL];`, and not `[prefs setObject:theUrl forKey:PREFS_FEED_URL];`.

Comment: @msgambel that stopped it from bombing with the error message in my question, but now I'm getting the error `-[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/crossfit/eRTq2' of class 'NSURL'.  Note that dictionaries and arrays in property lists must also contain only property values.`, and the value isn't saved.

Comment: You can't store NSURL in NSUserDefaults. My only thought is that there might be a global variable called prefs that was previously deallocated?

Comment: @daltonclaybrook - I didn't think so. I renamed my `*prefs` var to `*newPrefs` and received the same results (app bombs, same error message).

Comment: -[NSUserDefaults setURL:forKey:] is a thing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `setObject:forKey:` it must be one of the following data types. (From the apple documentation):

`The value parameter can be only property list objects: NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. For NSArray and NSDictionary objects, their contents must be property list objects.`

You should be using the following two methods:

`setURL:forKey:` and `URLForKey:`

Check out the documentation here: [NSUserDefaults Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Here are the currently supported methods for getting / setting `NSUserDefaults` values:

**Getting Default Values**

```
arrayForKey:
boolForKey:
dataForKey:
dictionaryForKey:
floatForKey:
integerForKey:
objectForKey:
stringArrayForKey:
stringForKey:
doubleForKey:
URLForKey:
```

**Setting Default Values**

```
setBool:forKey:
setFloat:forKey:
setInteger:forKey:
setObject:forKey:
setDouble:forKey:
setURL:forKey:
```

---

Regarding your edit,
you set up KVO on your `NSUserDefaults`, but you aren't unregistering them properly. When you use KVO on an object, you have to unregister KVO for *that* object, rather than just calling `removeObserver:` on `NSNotificationCenter`. Add the following to your `dealloc` method:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"feed_url" context:NULL];
```

What is most likely happening in this situation is you aren't unregistering KVO and so something else changes the `NSUserDefaults` and it tries to call your now dealloc`d view controller.

Comment: Thanks for setting me straight on this point. This however, does not resolve my core problem. I've edited my question (see Edit 3).

Comment: Edited my answer, when you use KVO on an object, you have to unregister KVO for *that* object, rather than just calling `removeObserver:` on `NSNotificationCenter`

Comment: Thanks @danielbeard. I've edited my logic to remove the observer, but now I'm getting the following error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'Cannot remove an observer <RssViewController 0xa15f5f0> for the key path "feed_url" from <NSNotificationCenter 0x947fb30> because it is not registered as an observer.'` Is the statement correct that I used to create the observer? `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"feed_url" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];`